# If I Find the "Objective Clue" with Gloria's Psychic Sensitivity, Does That Reveal the Objective

Tags: mansions-of-madness

I used Gloria Goldberg's Psychic Sensitivity to reveal the cards in the Ceremony Room, which contained Clue 1, which also says "Reveal Objective".

As I have to return the cards face down, does that mean the objective isn't revealed till I actually properly explore the room?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Gloria only **looks** at the cards, they are not revealed. Additionally, clue 1 is **always** the final clue to be discovered.

The wording on Gloria's Psychic Sensitivity Ability is:

> "Action: Once per game, **look** at all Exploration cards in the room of your choice (you must then return them in the same order)."

The [rulebook](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/mansions-of-madness/support/MansionsOfMadnessLoRes.pdf) states (page 9):

> **Explore Action** - The most common action that investigators perform on their turn is Exploring a Room. During setup, the keeper places face-down exploration cards in every room on the game board. **Investigators may reveal these cards** by performing an explore action in the room.
>
> **Clues**: These are the cards the investigators a ultimately attempting to discover. These cards have no artwork and are clearly labeled with a large number and a letter in the upper left corner. The number represents the level of the clue (**clue 1 is always the final clue to be discovered**), while the letter only matters during setup.